# Bumping navigation down - make it flush

Tags: css

On [this site](http://www.catonthecouchproductions.com/fish/) I am trying to drop down the nav towards the middle you will see how it doesn't match up. I have tried margin/padding/top/ css properties but nothing. On the edges see how it is about 3 or 4px off and if I bump it down it would be good. Why it is doing that?

UPDATE: [Here is my CSS](http://www.catonthecouchproductions.com/fish/css/style.css).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styles for the button images don't have any position in them. Try adding some style around the buttons:

```
.btn-fishing-trip 
{
    position:relative; top:3px;
}
.btn-combo
{
    position:relative; top:3px;
}
.btn-guest
{
    position:relative; top:3px;
}
.btn-contact
{
    position:relative; top:3px;
}
```